# sendfile doesn't work for empty stdin

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

Output from `strace` for non-empty stdin:

```
execve("./cat", ["./cat"], 0x7fff610af090 /* 37 vars */) = 0
sendfile(1, 0, NULL, 1048576)           = 4
sendfile(1, 0, NULL, 1048576)           = 0
close(0)                                = 0
exit(0)                                 = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Output from `strace` for empty stdin:

```
execve("./cat", ["./cat"], 0x7fff610af090 /* 37 vars */) = 0
sendfile(1, 0, NULL, 1048576)           = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
sendfile(1, 0, NULL, 1048576)           = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
sendfile(1, 0, NULL, 1048576)           = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
sendfile(1, 0, NULL, 1048576)           = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
sendfile(1, 0, NULL, 1048576)           = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
sendfile(1, 0, NULL, 1048576)           = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
sendfile(1, 0, NULL, 1048576)           = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
sendfile(1, 0, NULL, 1048576)           = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
sendfile(1, 0, NULL, 1048576)           = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
sendfile(1, 0, NULL, 1048576)           = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
sendfile(1, 0, NULL, 1048576)           = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
sendfile(1, 0, NULL, 1048576)           = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
...
```

`uname -a`:`5.3.8-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT @1572357769 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Did you also update GNU coreutils?

Comment: I did `sudo pacman -Syu --noconfirm`, so I think everything got updated.

Comment: `EINVAL` looks about the right error if one of the fd's isn't open. Is there a question in here?

Comment: Shouldn't stdin be open by default? If not how can I force program to open stdin?

Comment: How was that second command started?

Comment: Second command was started in that way: `./cat`

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be the intended behavior of the `sendfile` call. Let me cite Linus Torvalds:

> sendfile() on purpose only works on things that use the page cache.
> EINVAL is basically sendfile's way of saying "I would fall back on doing
> a read+write, so you might as well do it yourself in user space because
> it might actually be more efficient that way".
> (https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/sendfile.html)

So, `sendfile` will work with `stdin` only if the kernel knows that `stdin` is *actually* a file, not pipe, block device, or anything else.

I wrote a simple program to check it myself:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/sendfile.h>

int main() {
    sendfile(fileno(stdout), fileno(stdin), NULL, 8);
    perror("sendfile failed");
}
```

Running it with various redirections clearly shows that the `sendfile` call is successful only if the input is directly bound to a regular file, empty or not:

```
$ ./sendfile-test
sendfile failed: Invalid argument

$ ./sendfile-test < empty.txt
sendfile failed: Success

$ ./sendfile-test < non-empty.txt
(...)
sendfile failed: Success

$ ./sendfile-test < /dev/null
sendfile failed: Invalid argument

$ cat empty.txt | ./sendfile-test
sendfile failed: Invalid argument

$ cat non-empty.txt | ./sendfile-test
sendfile failed: Invalid argument

$ cat /dev/null | ./sendfile-test
sendfile failed: Invalid argument
```